# Copying a hashref in Perl

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to make a deep copy of a data structure in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388187/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-a-data-structure-in-perl)

I'm apparently misunderstanding something about how hashrefs work in Perl, and am here looking to correct that.

I need to get a copy of a hashref that I can fiddle with without modifying the original.  According to [my research](http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-hashes.html#copyph), copying a hashref is just as simple as using the equals operator:

```
my $hashref_copy = $hashref;
```

But as far as I can tell, all that does is make `$hashref_copy` a pointer to the original object.  Consider this toy bit of code:

```
my $hashref = {data => "fish"};

my $hashref_copy = $hashref;
$hashref_copy->{data} = "chips";

print "$hashref->{data}\n";
```

If `$hashref_copy` were really an independent copy, I'd expect this code to print "fish".  Instead, it prints "chips".

So either 1) I'm misunderstanding something or 2) Perl is broken.  I'm quite certain it isn't #2, in spite of what my ego would have me think.

Where am I going wrong?  And what do I need to do to make modifications to `$hashref_copy` *not* show up in the original `$hashref`?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546322/whats-the-best-way-to-deep-copy-a-hash-of-hashes-in-perl/1546334#1546334

Comment: Indeed, assigning one scalar to another does not result in any hash being copied. It just copies the value of the scalar. You are asking how to copy  a hash, create a reference to it, and place that reference in a scalar.

Comment: I am not sure if marking this as a duplicate is helpful - the referred question is about most efficient / clean way to make a deep copy.  This is a more basic question.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

When you copy a hashref into another scalar, you are copying a reference to the same hash.  This is similar to copying one pointer into another, but not changing any of the pointed-to memory.

You can create a shallow copy of a hash easily:

```
my $copy = { %$source };
```

The `%$source` bit in list context will expand to the list of key value pairs.  The curly braces (the anonymous hash constructor) then takes that list an creates a new hashref out of it.  A shallow copy is fine if your structure is 1-dimensional, or if you do not need to clone any of the contained data structures.

To do a full deep copy, you can use the core module `Storable`.

```
use Storable 'dclone';

my $deep_copy = dclone $source;
```

Comment: See also [`Clone`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Clone)

Comment: Using `Storable qw(clone)` worked fine for me in Perl 5.22 in 64-bit Linux. Using `Clone qw(clone)` causes exactly the same code to crash due to a segfault internal to Perl. Recommend using `Storable`.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, assignment just copies the reference (like copying a pointer value in other languages).  What you're looking for is called a "deep copy".

`Storable::dclone` seems to be one solution (`perldoc Storable` for more information).

[`Clone`](http://search.cpan.org/~garu/Clone-0.39/Clone.pm) is another (`perldoc clone`); thanks to Zaid for mentioning this in a comment.

Comment: Storable::dclone looks like overkill for my purposes, but thank you just the same; this is information worth having.

Comment: See also [`Clone`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Clone)

Answer (score 4):

If it's just a hash and all you're looking for is a copy of it:

```
my $hashref = {data => "a"};

my %hash_copy = %{$hashref}; # Create a copy of the hash that $hashref points to
my $hashref_copy = \%hash_copy; # Ref to %hash_copy
$hashref_copy->{data} = "b";

print "$hashref->{data}\n"; # Outputs 'a'
print "$hashref_copy->{data}\n"; # Outputs 'b'
```

Comment: Thank you; this would indeed do the trick.

Comment: @BlairHippo: You probably know this, but I'll mention that if some of the hash values are themselves references, this will only copy those references, not what they refer to.  Sounds like that's not a problem for you, but keep it in mind.

Comment: @Keith Thompson:  Thank you, and right on all counts.  :-)  I've documented that line of code to indicate that if the hashref in question is ever asked to hold something more interesting than scalars, a deep copy mechanism like Storable::dclone or Clone::clone will be necessary.

Comment: @BlairHippo: Might be easier to replace the comment with a call to `Storable::dclone` or `Clone::clone`.  Just a thought.