# How to make a shallow copy of a hash?

Tags: perl

I have a hash, which is filled up with data. I add it to an array. Then, I want to modify my hash, but make sure that what is in the array remains untouched. I'm trying this, doesn't work:

```
my @a;
my %h;
%h{foo} = 1;
push(@a, \%x);
%h = (); # here I clean the hash up
# but I want the array to still contain the data
```

I feel that I need to make a copy of it before adding to the array. How? I don't need a deep copy, my hash contains only strings.

Comment: The best solution is still to use a lexically scoped variable, and not try to reuse the same exact variable again. I'm sorry.

Comment: You can make a shallow copy of a hash using assignment: `my %h2 = %h`, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7083603/2173773) answer for copying a hash ref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't need a deep copy, my hash contains only strings.

Then you could make a shallow copy of the hash:

```
my @a;
my %h;
%h{foo} = 1;
my %copy_of_h = %h;
push(@a, \%copy_of_h);
%h = ();
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7083603/2173773) answer for how to copy a hash ref. For more on Perl data structures, see [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) and [perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#List-value-constructors).

Comment: Or just `push @a, { %h }`.

Comment: @TLP Yes of course! No need to create a new lexical variable here